# php string functions are not working

Tags: php

I am trying to use string function but these functions are not working in my program.

I am using following function.

```
echo strpos("set","namesetname");
echo strstr("set","namesetname");
echo stristr("set","namesetname");
echo strchr("set","namesetname");
```

all these functions are not displaying any things, nothing is returns or displayed on screen.

Comment: `strpos($mystring, $findme);` so you used them in wrong way! try `echo strpos("namesetname","set");`

Comment: read the docs ...http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Instead of declaring right away that one of the most wide spread programming languages does not work at all according to your expertise you might also have asked yourself if the problem is not _you_ not investing any effort into trying to understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### strpos, strstr, stristr and strchr

You used wrong syntax. Change params places reverse

```
echo strpos("namesetname", "set");
echo strstr("namesetname", "set");
echo stristr("namesetname", "set");
echo strchr("namesetname", "set");
```

#### strpos

`strpos` returns `BOOLEAN` or position.

Answer (score 0):

Using the functions as below will solve your issue..

```
echo strpos("namesetname","set");
echo strstr("namesetname","set");
echo stristr("namesetname","set");
echo strchr("namesetname","set");
```

Below are the some links for your reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php 
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php 
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php 
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.strchr.php